# SQLAlchemy 2.0 giving "the process cannot access the file" error while running test using Pytest on python flask application

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I am running a python flask application on Windows OS. I recently upgraded my python packages to use SQLAlchemy 2.0. I am using sqlite as database and pytest is used for testing.

After upgrading the packages, my tests tear down process started to fail on `os.remove(db_file_path)`. The error is shown below

```
 [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\db_file_dir\\test_db.sqlite'
```

My all test still passed and there is no assertion error or failure. When it tries to delete the DB file after executing all tests, it throw an exception.

Here is the sample code:

```
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
filepath = os.path.join(basedir, "test_db.sqlite")
test_database_uri = "sqlite:///" + filepath

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
 def _test_db():
 
    template_app = Application(dev_app_config)

    with template_app.get_app_context():
        test_db = template_app.database.reflect_db()
        test_engine = create_engine(test_database_uri)
        test_db .metadata.create_all(test_engine)
    yield test_engine

     test_engine.dispose()
     os.remove(filepath)
```

Any input or help in order to reach to possible solution would be appreciated.

Thanks